# Is there a way I can make a form button link to a different page after certain number of clicks?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a landing page with a form. I want to set up where every 10th person who signed up links to a "special" page where they receive a prize. For example: first 9 people will redirect to thankyou.html page where the 10th person will link to prize.html page. Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://form.relevanttools.com/rt-cgi-bin/satellite">
   <input type="hidden" name="code" value="12531"> <input type="hidden" name="db" value="project"> <input type="hidden" name="source" value="Prize"> <input type="hidden" name="optin" value=""> <input type="hidden" name="type" value="signup"> <input type="hidden" name="user_email_msg" value=""> <input type="hidden" name="admin_email_addr" value=""> <input type="hidden" name="redir" value="http://www.link.com/thankyou.html"> 
   <table border="0">
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>First Name*</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td> <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name*" size="20" value=""> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Last Name*</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td> <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name*" size="20" value=""> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Email*</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td> <input type="text" id="email" name="email*" size="20" value=""> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Age*</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td> <input type="text" id="age" name="age*" size="20" value=""> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Gender</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>
            <div class="align-left"> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male<br> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female<br> </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Zip</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td> <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" size="20" value=""> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Private Policy*</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td> <input type="checkbox" id="private_policy" name="private_policy" value="x"> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>Email Subscription</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td> <input type="checkbox" id="email_opt_in" name="email_opt_in" value="x"> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td><input type="submit" value = "Submit" ></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You would need to manage this on the server side.

Comment: Yes, just open a secure text file using CGI, and write "Count:1" in it. Next time, open it up and increment the integer by one. `"Open count-file; put count in variable; count = count+1".` Or other ways. What languages are you going to use for it? Is it even hosted yet?

Answer (score -1):

You could give the button a 10% probability of redirecting to the prize page - but that's the best without a server.

Javascript is client side. Meaning it has no way of knowing how other people have acted. The only way to know that is storing every click in a database and counting that.

Comment: Gotcha. I am using Relevant Tools as a form service. Maybe they can figure out a way. Thank you so much for your answer.